# Validating XML against XSD in javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xsd

I am looking out to validate an xml against the XSD using javascript/Jquery or any other API/library based on JS. I am not able to get any help on this. After doing research what I came to know is, people generally don't do this. I am forced to do so in my task. Please point me how can I achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have never done this, but a Web search on "javascript xml schema validation" shows some decent leads:

- xml.js, "a JavaScript library for client-side XML schema validation".
- In the context of ASP, there are apparently ActiveXObjects named "Msxml2.DOMDocument.4.0" and "Msxml2.DOMDocument.4.0".